# Make JavaScript Canvas Game Responsive with CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have an HTML canvas game that I want to make responsive by setting its width and height using CSS3.

The code for the JS canvas game is:

```
    <div id="main">
        <div class="game-box">
             <div class="game-container">
                  <div id="phaser-div">

                  </div>
             </div><!-- end game-container -->
        </div><!-- end game-box -->



    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var game = new Phaser.Game(832, 508, Phaser.WEBGL, 'phaser-div', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

var background;
var filter;

function preload() {

    var urlBase = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    game.load.image('phaser', urlBase + 'games/game001/game001-logo.png');
    game.load.script('filter', urlBase + 'games/game001/marble.js');

    this.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL; this.game.scale.setShowAll(); window.addEventListener('resize', function () { this.game.scale.refresh(); }); this.game.scale.refresh();
}

function create() {

    var logo = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'phaser');
    logo.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);

    background = game.add.sprite(0, 0);
    background.width = 832;
    background.height = 508;

    filter = game.add.filter('Marble', 832, 508);
    filter.alpha = 0.2;

    //  The following properties are available (shown at default values)

    //  filter.speed = 10.0;
    //  filter.intensity = 0.30;

    background.filters = [filter];

}

function update() {

    filter.update();

}
    </script>
```

Live Link: 
http://revolutionarydeveloper.com/project-games/index.html

I tried setting something like #phaser-div canvas {width: 100%; height: 470px;} but it doesnt seem to work. How can I make it responsive using CSS3 and modify the width and height using media queries?

Many Thanks

Note: This game utilizes Phaser.JS. Including its link in case it is relevant. 
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/phaser/2.6.2/phaser.js

Answer (score 1):

phaser has its own codes for making game responsive

```
Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
```

look at http://phaser.io/news/2015/02/responsive-games-basics

Comment: This is good, but there is a problem with it. I have to refresh the page for the phaser to scale properly i.e. it is responsive on page load . But if i resize the page, it does not scale properly. Is there a way I could get this to update everytime the page resizes? If not, can I control the width and height using CSS?

Comment: you have to code it for, such as attaching resize event to body and decide on the basis of resized property because when it comes to phaser it draws canvas frequently so it cannot be responsive like bootstrap (phaser canvas is not only element we can say that it is animation drawing).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation anshu. If you could kindly guide me on how to write that code for the phaser canvas to resize according to the page width, I would really appreciate it since my JavaScript skill level is very intermediate.

Comment: I have something like this already in the code: 

this.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL; this.game.scale.setShowAll(); window.addEventListener('resize', function () { this.game.scale.refresh(); }); this.game.scale.refresh();

This should work when windows is resized, but apparently it only works when it is refreshed.

Comment: this.time.events.add(200, function() {            MyGame.calculateDimensions();            this.scale.setGameSize(MyGame.canvasWidth, MyGame.canvasHeight);        }, this);

Answer (score 0):

```
Phaser method

this.time.events.add(200, function() { 
   MyGame.calculateDimensions();            
   this.scale.setGameSize(MyGame.canvasWidth, MyGame.canvasHeight);        
}, this);


jQuery method

$(window).resize(function() { resizeGame(); } );
    function resizeGame() {

    var innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var gameRatio = innerWidth/innerHeight;

    game.width = Math.ceil(320*gameRatio);
    game.height = 320;
    game.stage.bounds.width = Math.ceil(320*gameRatio);
    game.stage.bounds.height = 320;
    game.scale.refresh();

}
```

Comment: jQuery method doesnt work. I added the phaser method in the function preload, did not work either. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: look at https://github.com/EnclaveGames/Enclave-Phaser-Template/ is fully responsive